# Troubleshoting slow running queries/jobs in Azure Databricks

Tags: performance, azure, troubleshooting, databricks

I have Azure Databricks workspace with cluster configured to run Standard 6.4 runtime (Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11). Cluster uses shared metastore (Azure MySQL). I'm trying to figure out possible way to troubleshoot sporadically slow execution of jobs/queires - I have a test SELECT query which normally runs within 2-3 minutes but couple of times a day it takes 15 minutes. What would be the best way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Look into Spark UI to understand how many Spark jobs are running for that query, etc. Also, it's recommended to upgrade to newest DBR versions, or at least 7.3 - Spark 3 solves a lot of problems with skewed partitions & other inefficiencies

Comment: Comments should only be used for asking for clarification, or to leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post, or to add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated), or to provide site usage guidance.  See the [help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for details.

Comment: Post from your 'shared metastore' the 2-3 minute A) query and results of B) EXPLAIN SELECT ...your query...; and C) SHOW CREATE TABLE each_table_used or joined ;   for analysis.  Is your application on SHARED or DEDICATED Azure OS?  Which OS?  Rotating, SSD or NVME data storage?